# The insert statement and foreign key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

The error i am facing:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "fk_anm_intake_code". The conflict occurred in database "J.Does",
>   table "dbo.intake_codes", column 'intake_code'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Script for the above mentioned error:

```
insert into animals
(anm_name,anm_species,anm_breed,anm_age,anm_gender,anm_size,anm_spayorneuter,anm_intake_date,anm_intake_code,anm_notes)
 values 
('Tom', 'Canine', 'Mix.pit/Poodle', 8.80, 'M', 'SM', 'Y', 12/23/16,'C', 'Needs additional water/Hoursebroken'),
('Chi', 'Feline', 'House', 0.80, 'F', 'SM', 'Y', 11/11/16, 'F', 'Very affectionate' ),
('Lin', 'Canine', 'Beagle', 2.30, 'M', 'SM', 'N', 1/17/16, 'B', 'Hoursebroken/loves to play ball'),
('Frisky', 'Feline', 'Mix.pit/Poodle', 11.50, 'F', 'Med',' N', 12/2/16, 'B', 'Best in low activity home'),
('Shady', 'Canine', 'House', 4.50, 'F', 'Med', 'Y', 1/16/17, 'C ', 'Null'),
('Sparky', 'Canine', 'Mix.pit/Poodle', 4.10, 'F', 'Lrg', 'N', 1/17/17, 'F', 'Not housebroken/love kids/gentle'),
('Lucy', 'Feline', 'House', 1.10, 'F', 'XL', 'Y', 12/3/16, 'E', 'Null'),
('Blue', 'Canine', 'Lab/Pit.Mixed', 1.20, 'F', 'SM', 'N', 2/4/17, 'B', 'Not housebroken')
```

Please HELP!!

Comment: if you insert something into a table with a foreign key make sure the value inserted in that column also exists in the parent table

Comment: Yes, I already check what I put in the parent table is the same as the insert table, but its not working

Comment: Can you update your question and include the two table structures.

Comment: -- 2.2 ADD TABLE CONSTRAINTS: animals

 Alter table animals
ADD constraint pk_anm_id PRIMARY KEY (anm_id)




-- 2.3 ADD TABLE CONSTRAINTS: intake_codes
Alter table intake_codes
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_intake_code PRIMARY KEY (intake_code)
 
These are what I have and my question is how to fix the conflict between insert statement and foreign key

Answer (score 0):

You must be trying to insert a value into animals.anm_intake_code that doesn't exist in the dbo.intake_codes table.

Looking at your query...

```
INSERT INTO animals (
    anm_name,anm_species,anm_breed,anm_age,anm_gender,anm_size,anm_spayorneuter,anm_intake_date,anm_intake_code,anm_notes
) VALUES (
    'Tom', 'Canine', 'Mix.pit/Poodle', 8.80, 'M', 'SM', 'Y', 12/23/16,'C', 'Needs additional water/Hoursebroken'
), (
    'Chi', 'Feline', 'House', 0.80, 'F', 'SM', 'Y', 11/11/16, 'F', 'Very affectionate'
), (
    'Lin', 'Canine', 'Beagle', 2.30, 'M', 'SM', 'N', 1/17/16, 'B', 'Hoursebroken/loves to play ball'
), (
    'Frisky', 'Feline', 'Mix.pit/Poodle', 11.50, 'F', 'Med',' N', 12/2/16, 'B', 'Best in low activity home'
), (
    'Shady', 'Canine', 'House', 4.50, 'F', 'Med', 'Y', 1/16/17, 'C ', 'Null'
), (
    'Sparky', 'Canine', 'Mix.pit/Poodle', 4.10, 'F', 'Lrg', 'N', 1/17/17, 'F', 'Not housebroken/love kids/gentle'
), (
    'Lucy', 'Feline', 'House', 1.10, 'F', 'XL', 'Y', 12/3/16, 'E', 'Null'
), (
    'Blue', 'Canine', 'Lab/Pit.Mixed', 1.20, 'F', 'SM', 'N', 2/4/17, 'B', 'Not housebroken'
)
```

...you are trying to insert 'C', 'F', 'B', and 'E'. Which of those values is not in the dbo.intake_codes?

Comment: ALTER TABLE animals
 ADD constraint fk_anm_intake_code FOREIGN KEY (anm_intake_code) REFERENCES intake_codes(intake_code),
   constraint ck_anm_intake_code CHECK (anm_intake_code in ('B','C','D','E','F','N'))

This is what I have

Comment: Can you confirm the data is actually in the dbo.intake_codes table? I.e. what are the results of SELECT * FROM dbo.intake_codes?

Comment: CHECK (anm_intake_code in ('B','C','D','E','F','N')) is a constraint and will only allow those values, but it does not mean the rows are actually in the table.

Comment: B  Stray/At Large
C  Relinquished by Owner
D  Owner Intended Euthanasia
E  Transferred in
F  Other Intakes these are what I got from that select statement

Comment: What is the datatype of the anm_intake_code field on both dbo.intake_code and dbo.animals?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have the 'N' `intake_code` defined in the `dbo.intake_codes` table. You might fix it inserting the missing value

```
insert into dbo.intake_codes(intake_code) select 'N'
```